# Design optimal Solr Schema

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solarium

Hello i have problem with design of schema in Solr. I have a transcript of a telephone conversation in this format. I parse it at individual fields.
I have this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">01.cn</field>
<field name="t">0<br /> 1<br /> 2<br /> 2 <br /> 3 <br /> ....</field>
<field name="st">0.00<br /> 1.54<br /> 1.54<br /> 1.54 <br /> 1.57 <br /> ....</field>
<field name="et">1.54<br /> 1.54<br /> 1.57<br /> 1.57 <br /> 1.7 <br /> ....</field>
<field name="w">_SILENCE_<br /> <s><br /> HELLO<br /> HALLO <br /> _DELETE_ <br /> ....</field>
<field name="p">0.000000<br /> 1<br /> 1<br /> 2.06115e-009 <br /> 1 <br /> ....</field>
<field name="c">0<br /> 0<br /> 0<br /> 0 <br /> 0 <br /> ....</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

I displayed it in html document, and therefore i used the `<br /`>.

This is a original document:

```
T=0 ST=0.00 ET=1.54 W=_SILENCE_ P=0.000000 C=0
T=1 ST=1.54 ET=1.54 W=<s> P=1 C=0
T=2 ST=1.54 ET=1.57 W=HELLO P=1 C=0
T=2 ST=1.54 ET=1.57 W=HALLO P=2.06115e-009 C=0
T=3 ST=1.57 ET=1.70 W=_DELETE_ P=1 C=0
T=3 ST=1.57 ET=1.70 W=NO P=2.06115e-009 C=0
T=4 ST=1.70 ET=2.12 W=HOW P=1 C=0
T=5 ST=2.12 ET=2.18 W=ARE_ P=0.25 C=0
T=5 ST=2.12 ET=2.18 W=_DELETE_ P=0.25 C=0
..........................................
..........................................

Id - filename
T = Segment
ST = Start time
ET = End time
W = Word
P = Probability
C = Chanel
```

I want to search for example word which is to time 1.57 `(w:HeLLO) AND (t:[0 TO 1.57])`. But if i have all data in one field (t, st,et ...) then it doesn't work.
It find all files where is hello a further time than 1.57.

Do you have any ideas how it make it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate core with one document for each (word, time) combination, and query that core instead.